# VueJS component not refreshing Axios GET request although there is a key

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuejs3

I build a component "article" which contains a component "vote". As you may have guessed: every article has positive and negative votes. I call my vote component like this in "Article.vue":

```
<votes :voteId="$route.params.id" type="actu" :key="'actuVote-'+$route.params.id"/>
```

And here is my vote component:

```
<template>
  <div :key="`vote-${type}-${voteId}`">
    <span>
      <span
        class="vote"
        :class="{ selectionne: voteUser === 'POSITIF' }"
        @click="e => vote(e.target,voteId,'POSITIF')">
        
      </span>
      {{ votes.pos }}
    </span>
    <span>
      <span
        class="vote"
        :class="{ selectionne: voteUser === 'NEGATIF' }"
        @click="e => vote(e.target,voteId,'NEGATIF')">
        
      </span>
      {{ votes.neg }}
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  defineComponent, onMounted, toRefs, ref,
} from 'vue';

import axios from 'axios';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Votes',
  props: ['voteId', 'type'],
  setup(props) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
    const { voteId, type } = toRefs(props);
    const votes = ref({
      pos: 0,
      neg: 0,
    });
    const voteUser = ref('');

    async function fetchVotes(idVote, typeVote) {
      const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/votes/${idVote}/${typeVote}`);
      try {
        votes.value.neg = +res.data.filter((x) => x.vote === 'NEGATIF')[0].nombre;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Pas de vote négatif: ${e}`);
      }
      try {
        votes.value.pos = +res.data.filter((x) => x.vote === 'POSITIF')[0].nombre;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Pas de vote positif: ${e}`);
      }
    }

    async function verifVote(idVote) {
      const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/votes/verif/${type.value}/${idVote}`);
      if (res.data.length > 0) {
        voteUser.value = res.data[0].vote;
      }
    }

    async function vote(elt, idVote, typeVote) {
      if (!elt.classList.contains('recherche')) {
        elt.classList.toggle('recherche');
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/votes/`, { id: idVote, type: type.value, vote: typeVote });
        if (res.data.length > 0) {
          votes.value[typeVote === 'POSITIF' ? 'pos' : 'neg'] += 1;
          if (typeVote !== voteUser.value && voteUser.value !== '') {
            votes.value[typeVote === 'POSITIF' ? 'neg' : 'pos'] -= 1;
          }
        } else {
          votes.value[typeVote === 'POSITIF' ? 'pos' : 'neg'] -= 1;
        }
        voteUser.value = res.data;
        elt.classList.toggle('recherche');
      }
    }

    onMounted(async () => {
      fetchVotes(voteId.value, type.value);
      verifVote(voteId.value, type.value);
    });

    return {
      votes,
      vote,
      voteUser,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped>
.vote {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes fade {
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.2; }
    to { opacity: 1.0; }
}

.recherche {
  animation:fade 500ms infinite;
}

.selectionne {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
</style>
```

My problem is: when I am on `actu/1`, I put a positive vote, then I go on `actu/2` and put a negative vote, if I go back to `actu/1`, the correct article loads correctly, but I have the votes as if my previous vote for `actu/1` was not taken into account.
If I refresh `actu/1` and `actu/2` and do not vote, everything is fine, the proper votesdisplay correctly.

When I look in the network console, I see the 200 HTTP code is particular: `200 OK (from disk cache)`. Maybe there is a way to force axios to really make the HTTP request again.

I tried this but it breaks everything in my app:

```
axiosInstance.defaults.headers = {
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  Pragma: 'no-cache',
  Expires: '0',
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the article component have also a `key` ?

Comment: Yes, sir, it does.